# How to grab data from the last 13 months?

Tags: sql, date

So I have this code, this is for grabbing data for the last 11 month of sale including the current month, make it a whole year. What do I have to do to change it to grabbing data for the last 12 months plus current month? I know I have to change something on the right(select period)... but not sure

In this one, the left function shows how to get the current year (2014 ) minus 1 to give 2013.. but I don't understand the right function, what does 2 mean?
Thanks

```
period <= (
    SELECT Period 
    FROM dbo.FiscalDates 
    WHERE (Date = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 102))) and period >= (
convert(varchar, left((
    SELECT Period 
    FROM dbo.FiscalDates 
    WHERE (Date = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 102))),4)-1)+'-'+
convert(varchar, right((
    SELECT Period 
    FROM dbo.FiscalDates 
    WHERE (Date = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 102))),2)))
group by prodnum, period, WhseNum
```

Comment: Woah why are you converting the date to `VARCHAR`???

Comment: `WHERE YourColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))`

Comment: @Zane, I use that conversion all the time to convert the date to a more readable form that can be exported (in this case, `yyyy.mm.dd`).  See http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx for various conversions.  However, I'm still not sure why's he using it in the Where clause.

Comment: The format of the period in my table is 2014-04, 2014-03... That's why I thought I had to convert to varchar. I tried the code as suggested but I can't put 2014-03 as "month" on it :(.

Comment: Then your problem is how you're storing your date. You need to store dates in the `DATE` datatype. Don't worry about how the date is formatted until it's time to display.

Comment: @PowerUser yeah but you don't do your `WHERE` clause this way?!

Comment: @Zane, no I would not do my where clause that way unless maybe the date was stored as text (in that case, I might try a Cast() first).  Your suggestions are correct.

Comment: So I need to cast my fiscal dates first?

Answer (score 17):

Whoah buddy I think you may be overcomplicating things here. If you want to get data for the past X number of months then just use `DATEADD` it's a very [useful function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

All you need to do then is

```
select
    YourColumns
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

and bam there you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DECLARE 
        @FormYear AS INT,
        @FormMonth AS INT,
        @ToYear AS INT,
        @ToMonth AS INT,
        @FromDate AS DATE,
        @ToDate AS DATE

        SET @FormYear=YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()))
        SET @FormMonth=MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()))

        SET @ToYear=YEAR(GETDATE())
        SET @ToMonth=MONTH(GETDATE())

        SET @FromDate= CAST(CAST(@FormMonth AS VARCHAR) +'-'+'01'+ '-' +CAST(@FormYear AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)
        SET @ToDate= CAST(CAST(@ToMonth AS VARCHAR) +'-' + '01'+'-' + CAST(@ToYear AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)
```

After that, just select-

```
  YourDateField Between @FormDate AND @ToDate
```