# How do get last 13 months data from database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following table I want to get the last 13 months data based on my customer orders and months:

```
create table dynamicorders 
(
    order_date date,
    order_total number(8),
    name varchar2(100)
);


insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-01-05', 705, 'jhone'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-01-15', 715, 'steve'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-01-17', 50, 'jhone'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-02-09', 802, 'mular'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-03-12', 812, 'steve'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-03-29', 829, 'steve'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-04-03', 903, 'jhone'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-04-29', 150, 'steve'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2021-05-19', 100, 'steve'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2022-01-10', 300, 'steve');
insert into dynamicorders values( '2022-01-18', 400, 'mular');
```

Here is the screenshot of the result set I need:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-01-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Jan",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-02-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Feb",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-03-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Mar",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-04-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Apr",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-05-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-May",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-06-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Jun",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-07-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Jul",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-08-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Aug",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-09-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Sep",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-10-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Oct",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-11-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Nov",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2021-12-01' THEN order_total END) AS "21-Dec",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'YY') WHEN DATE '2021-01-01' THEN order_total END) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN DATE '2022-01-01' THEN order_total END) AS "22-Jan"
FROM   dynamicorders d
GROUP BY name
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | NAME | 21-Jan | 21-Feb | 21-Mar | 21-Apr | 21-May | 21-Jun | 21-Jul | 21-Aug | 21-Sep | 21-Oct | 21-Nov | 21-Dec | TOTAL | 22-Jan |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | jhone | 755 | *null* | *null* | 903 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1658 | *null* |
> | steve | 715 | *null* | 1641 | 150 | 100 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2606 | 300 |
> | mular | *null* | 802 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 802 | 400 |

If you want the last 13 months, rather than specific months then you **CANNOT** provide dynamic column names relevant to the months (unless you use dynamic SQL) and can use:

```sql
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -12) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-12",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -11) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-11",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -10) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-10",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -9) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-9",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -8) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-8",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -7) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-7",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -6) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-6",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -5) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-5",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -4) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-4",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -3) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-3",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -2) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-2",
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  -1) THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH-1",
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -12) <= order_date AND order_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN order_total END) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE TRUNC(order_date, 'MM') WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') THEN order_total END) AS "CURRENT_MONTH"
FROM   dynamicorders d
GROUP BY name
```

Which outputs:

> | NAME | CURRENT_MONTH-12 | CURRENT_MONTH-11 | CURRENT_MONTH-10 | CURRENT_MONTH-9 | CURRENT_MONTH-8 | CURRENT_MONTH-7 | CURRENT_MONTH-6 | CURRENT_MONTH-5 | CURRENT_MONTH-4 | CURRENT_MONTH-3 | CURRENT_MONTH-2 | CURRENT_MONTH-1 | TOTAL | CURRENT_MONTH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | jhone | 755 | *null* | *null* | 903 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1658 | *null* |
> | steve | 715 | *null* | 1641 | 150 | 100 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2606 | 300 |
> | mular | *null* | 802 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 802 | 400 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=248c21986efab005262150da4a2ab0de)*

Comment: hi @MTO thank u very much a small bug is in your query this query always show jan-21 to jan-22 this will not show last 13 months records for example on 1st feb i want query from feb-21 to feb-22

Comment: @ayansahib It is not a bug but an interpretation of the question where the question was not specific about the expected behaviour for future dates. Regardless, I've added a version that will get the last 13 months.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *typical* use case for a `PIVOT` function.

```
with mon as (
select 
trunc(ORDER_DATE,'MM') ORDER_MONTH, ORDER_TOTAL, NAME
from dynamicorders)
select * from mon
PIVOT (sum(ORDER_TOTAL) ORDER_TOTAL  for (ORDER_MONTH) in 
(date'2021-01-01' as "21-Jan",
 date'2021-02-01' as "21-Feb",
 date'2021-03-01' as "21-Mar",
 date'2021-04-01' as "21-Apr",
 date'2021-05-01' as "21-May",
 date'2021-06-01' as "21-Jun",
 date'2021-07-01' as "21-Jul",
 date'2021-08-01' as "21-Aug",
 date'2021-09-01' as "21-Sep",
 date'2021-10-01' as "21-Oct",
 date'2021-11-01' as "21-Nov",
 date'2021-12-01' as "21-Dec"
)
);
```

For *dynamic* last N months you will need a *dynamic* SQL, as `PIVOT` requires *static* expression.

Comment: You do not need dynamic SQL for the last 13 (dynamic) months. That can be done with conditional aggregation. Its only if you want to dynamically assign identifiers relevant to the months that you would need dynamic SQL.

Comment: For sure @MT0 I can see your answer, but to use `PIVOT` dynamic SQL is required as the `for` clause must be static. This was my point, which actually makes `PIVOT` less atractive toward yours pre-pivot solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM dynamicorders WHERE order_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Use the [DATEADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) function, It takes three parameters `DATEADD(interval, number, date)`.


The first Parameter is *interval* i.e ***(YEAR/MONTH/DAY)***.

The second parameter is *number* i.e ***(The number of times you want to increment the date based on interval).***

The third parameter is *date* i.e ***Date that you want to modify***


Check this answer for more information [Grab data from the last 13 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156062/how-to-grab-data-from-the-last-13-months/23156186).

Also check out this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dateadd-function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20DateAdd,Weekday%20(%22w%22).) of `DATEADD` on Microsoft official page for detailed information about this function.

Comment: There's no DATEADD function in Oracle, so .. that won't work. Besides, code you posted doesn't return result in desired format anyway.

Comment: yes true dateAdd function not available in oracle